# AWS load balance between regions

Tags: load-balancing

*Is it possible in AWS to create load balancing between two regions ?.Assuming two of my identical web servers are running in different region*

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know, the native ELB **does not** allow cross-region load balancing.

If you have a Route53 managed domain (or can afford to set this up), you should use [latency-based routing](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/latency-based-multi-region-routing-now-available-for-aws/) to your various instances.

Alternatively, you could self-host a load balancer (HAProxy/nginx) on an EC2 instance, but this is unlikely to provide the same latency benefits as the first solution.

Comment: indeed, ELBs are meant to balance traffic towards availability zones. Beside, packet losses between regions can be problematic. Route53 sounds like a good plan.